# Beginner C++, pointers and inheritance errors

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am a beginner c++ programmer well versed in csharp however..

For an assignment of mine we have to create a text based maze game, I so far have a header file which contains direction declarations and methods which set directions N,S,W,E

In the main I have gets and sets to set which direction rooms can go in. Below is examples of the code I have included one of each statements to cut the length, i.e only south get and sets.

```
void Room::setS(Room* nextRoom)
{
south = nextRoom;
}

Room* Room::gS(){return south;}

Room* A = new Room("A");
Room* B = new Room("B");

A->setE(B);
A->setS(E);

Room* myPosistion = A;
string location = *myPosistion->gName();

while(location !="L")
{
    cout << "You are In Room "<< location << endl;
    }
```

In the while loop I need to be able to access the Room::Methods, (Room::gS()), so something along the lines of

```
if(location->gS() == NULL
//do nothing
else 
{
  cout<<"1. South"<<endl;
}
```

The problem is, I cannot get the location variable to access the Room:: methods, I know im missing something very basic but just cannot get my finger on it..

Thanks for the help

Comment: I know you're from C#, but in C++ `new` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: You're having a fundamental misunderstanding here. The fact that a method on `Room` returned a string does not make the string a Room, or have any of it's methods.

Comment: `location` is a string, not a `Room*`.

Comment: And you don't need all those pointers. And the while loop is an infinite loop. And the bottom code snippet is missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Hi, I only snipped part of the code, the part that Im trying to figure out is how to get location to use the methods like gS()

Comment: Just make the changes, like they said. Either change `location` to a `Room*`, or change the result of `gS()` to a `string`. Either change will make `location` the same type as `gS()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the pointer to the object instead of the string containing the name

try something more in the lines of :

```
while(myPosistion->gName().compare("L") != 0 )
{
    cout << "You are In Room "<< myPosistion->gName() << endl;
    if( myPosistion->gS() != NULL )
    {
        cout << "1. South : "<< myPosistion->gS()->gName() << endl;
    }
    //TODO some processing here!
}
```

when you use the location variable (`string`), you the reference to the object

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer, however     while(myPosistion->gName().compare("L") != 0 )  throws the error must have a class type, and myPos->gname() only lists the memory location when displaying, rather than the room :) Thanks

Comment: You never said what gName() is defined as.